# How to control SVG filter attribute values using CSS?

Tags: css, css-animations, svg-filters, css-variables

I want to create animation in CSS, part of which I need to control the values of the SVG filter attributes.

Below, I try to call a CSS variable within the **specularConstant** attribute, and the browser returns an error.

Alternatively, is it possible to set the attribute using a selector in the CSS code, or is there any way to control an SVG attribute like this, via CSS?

Below a Reproducible Example:

```css
@property --illumination-power {
  syntax: '<number>';
  initial-value: 1;
  inherits: true
}

:root {
  animation: my-animation 5s;
}

@keyframes my-animation {
  0% {
    --illumination-power: 0;
  }
  100% {
    --illumination-power: 1.2;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100vw" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <filter id="spotlight">
      <feSpecularLighting specularConstant="var(--illumination-power)"
      specularExponent="10" lighting-color="white">
        <fePointLight x="200" y="100" z="70"/>
      </feSpecularLighting>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect id="light-background" x="-500%" y="-500%" width="1000%" height="1000%" fill-opacity="0" filter="url(#spotlight)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the SVG `<animate>` element or JavaScript to do it.

Comment: So there is no way to control it through CSS?
It's important to me that you have control over it through CSS because that way I can integrate it as part of a systemic animation.

Comment: Filter attributes are not exposed to CSS. Sorry. If you want to control it via CSS, then you need to define as many filters as you have frames and use CSS to switch the filter applied once per frame. Which is insane - better to use JavaScript.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some way to control this through CSS.
thanks anyway.

Comment: If the answer is correct then please mark it as such.